# Plotting a list of 3D points in SymPy

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, ipython

If I have a list of 3D points, say

```
pts = [(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,3)]
```

and I wanted to use SciPy to plot them, how would I do that? I've tried

```
plot3d([Point(0,0,0),Point(1,0,0),Point(0,2,0),Point(0,0,3)], (x, -5, 5), (y, -5, 5))
```

but that results in this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-851ee4534010> in <module>()
----> 1 plot3d([Point(0,0,0),Point(1,0,0),Point(0,2,0),Point(0,0,3)], (x, -5, 5), (y, -5, 5))

/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in plot3d(*args, **kwargs)
   1618     series = []
   1619     plot_expr = check_arguments(args, 1, 2)
-> 1620     series = [SurfaceOver2DRangeSeries(*arg, **kwargs) for arg in plot_expr]
   1621     plots = Plot(*series, **kwargs)
   1622     if show:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Optimally, the solution would plot a polyhedron (tetrahedron) with those verticies, or connect them with line segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot these points with `scatter`. If you want to connect them with line segments, one possible way would be to first plot the points and then connect them, like this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# plotting the points
pts = [(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,3)]
for p in pts:
    ax.scatter(p[0], p[1], p[2], zdir='z', c='r')

# plotting lines for each point pair
for a, b in itertools.product(pts, pts):
    x = np.linspace(a[0], b[0], 100)
    y = np.linspace(a[1], b[1], 100)
    z = np.linspace(a[2], b[2], 100)
    ax.plot(x, y, z)

ax.legend()
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 2)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 3)

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]